# The edit button isn't showing up in my ASPxGridView

Tags: asp.net, aspxgridview

I have an ASPxGridView on my .aspx site with the flag "ShowEditButton" set to true and my LinqDataSource set to enable updating.

When looking at the page in Design view the button shows up.

Since it doesn't let me add all the code without having some more text, here is some meaningless text to satisfy StackOverflow's algorithm.

Here is the code for the GridViewCommandColumn and the LinqDataSource:

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="myGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    ClientIDMode="AutoID" DataSourceID="myDataSource"
    OnRowInserting="gridView_RowInserting" OnRowUpdating="gridView_RowUpdating"
    OnCustomButtonInitialize="gridView_CustomButtonInitialize" OnCommandButtonInitialize="gridView_CommandButtonInitialize"
    Caption="A Caption" KeyFieldName="id">
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="0">
        </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
        <dx:GridViewCommandColumn VisibleIndex="1" Width="100px" ShowEditButton="True" ShowNewButtonInHeader="True" ShowDeleteButton="True">
        </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="field1" VisibleIndex="2">
            <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="field2" VisibleIndex="3">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="field3" VisibleIndex="4">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="field4" VisibleIndex="5">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="field5" VisibleIndex="6">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="field6" VisibleIndex="7">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="field7" VisibleIndex="8">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="field8" VisibleIndex="9">
            <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="field9" 
            ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="10">
            <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="field10" VisibleIndex="11">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="field11" VisibleIndex="12">
            <PropertiesTextEdit DisplayFormatString="C2">
            </PropertiesTextEdit>
            <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="field12" VisibleIndex="13">
            <PropertiesTextEdit DisplayFormatString="C2">
            </PropertiesTextEdit>
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataDateColumn FieldName="field13" VisibleIndex="14">
            <PropertiesDateEdit DisplayFormatString="G">
            </PropertiesDateEdit>
            <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
        </dx:GridViewDataDateColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataDateColumn FieldName="field14" VisibleIndex="15">
            <PropertiesDateEdit DisplayFormatString="G">
            </PropertiesDateEdit>
            <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
        </dx:GridViewDataDateColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="field15" VisibleIndex="16">
            <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="field16" VisibleIndex="17" 
            GroupIndex="0" SortIndex="0" SortOrder="Descending">
            <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    </Columns>
    <SettingsPager PageSize="50">
    </SettingsPager>
    <Settings ShowFilterRow="True" />
</dx:ASPxGridView>

<asp:LinqDataSource ID="myDataSource" runat="server" 
        ContextTypeName="myDataContext" EntityTypeName="" 
        TableName="myTable" 
        EnableDelete="True" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True">
        </asp:LinqDataSource>
```

Comment: Please share your code. Are you sure it's not AutoGenerateEditButton?

Comment: I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: The full GridView code may help too. My guess is that a setting in the gridview is overriding showing the button. Are any rows returned in the data to display in the grid? Edit may not show if there are none. Showing the full gridview code will give a much clearer picture.

Comment: Again, edited the post accordingly.

Comment: Could these code behind functions be doing something to stop the buttons from showing at runtime?   OnCustomButtonInitialize="gridView_CustomButtonInitialize" OnCommandButtonInitialize="gridView_CommandButtonInitialize"   Maybe comment those out and make sure they display without those.  Take away anything extra for the moment.

Comment: That did the trick. Cheers!